# SQL Server document store vs MongoDB

Tags: json, sql-server, mongodb, document

do you know the difference between MongoDB and SQL Server "document store" ( Json support). Is it the same thing ? Or Sql is now same as mongoDB to store document ?

I would like to insert/update/delete in one aggregate command the most fastest.
(10k<=X<=40Million of data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pair each key with a complex data structure known as a document. It can contain many Different key-value pairs, or key-array pairs, or even nested documents. MongoDB is the most popular of these databases.

Sql is a relational database , MongoDB is a Non-Relational Database

NoSQL databases are more scalable and provide superior performance, over a large amount of data. Lighter than relational databases. It is possible to handle rapidly changing structured, semi-structured, and unstructured data which is relational databases cannot perform.